# Joomla SEF URL to custom component task

Tags: php, joomla

I am quite new to Joomla! and building a custom component to provide API services. 
Below is the url to the component function :

http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_componentA&task=ajax.functionA&format=json

I would like to change it to become :

http://www.example.com/componentA/functionA

Is there any idea I could achieve that?

I tried rewrite on .htaccess for that particular url but Joomla! will redirect it back to index.php.

Also tried installing joomsef by ARTIO but it did not work.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: remember localhost cannot be accessed from outside. Also you should first tell what have you tried so far and where you failed? check this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yea i understand that. The url is just an example. I'll update the question, also i found the solution to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few more hours of testing I've solved it. I've added router.php to my component folder with two functions in it "[componentName]BuildRoute" and "[componentName]ParseRoute" to override original function. Refer [Joomla! Documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/Search_Engine_Friendly_URLs).

**[componentName]BuildRoute** will be the function building SEF or custom URL.
- This function will return an array where element in it will be concatenate to build the custom URL.
- Depends on what you return in the array will determine the URLstructure.

*For eg.* :

http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_componentA&task=ajax.functionA&format=json

BuildRoute need to return `array("ajax", "functionA");`

and translate into http://www.example.com/component/componentA/ajax/functionA

**[componentName]ParseRoute** will be the function to convert your custom URL back to internal URL.

- This function will input an array where each of the element will be use to determine the internal URL.
- Then using the parameter to rebuild a return array that map back to internal link

For Eg. :

http://www.example.com/component/componentA/ajax/functionA

ParseRoute parameter will be `array("ajax", "functionA")`

ParseRoute needs to return `array("task" => "ajax.createPolicyResult", "format"=>"json");`

http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_componentA&task=ajax.functionA&format=json

---

I cant remove the "component" from the URL else it won't work but its OK for me. As the "componentA" is needed as well so that it will call the router.php file in my custom component folder.

Hope this help =)